How to access "Content" files in incremental source generator?
I'm trying to build an incremental source generator that will output nested classes with strings for each content file in my project containing its file path like so:
public static class Content
{
    public static class SomeDirectory
    {
        public static readonly string MyFile = "Content/SomeDirectory/MyFile.png";
    }
}

A "content" file is a file marked via the Content build action: <Content Include="Content\foobar.png" />.
In my other source generators I have marked any files I needed with the AdditionalFiles build action and then accessed them through the AdditionalTextsProvider property on the source generator context. However for these files they need to be marked as Content and as such do not appear in the AdditionalTextsProvider list of files.
Is it possible to access the content files similarly to AdditionalFiles-files or will I need to resort to manual I/O operations (which I really want to avoid inside a source generator)?

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

@Progman Did you even read the question? This is not a "code snippet does not work" question, I'm asking if it is at all possible to access Content files through source generators...
